# how do add a dot to a variable to be used as selector in less

Tags: css, less

I'm currently getting this output:

```
.'teal-dark' { color: #xxx; }
```

What I want is this: {

```
.teal-dark { color; #xxx; }
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
 @teal-dark: #xxx;
.@{currentMember} div { background: ~"@{@{currentMember}}" };
```

Comment: That syntax would work fine mate but it depends on whether you are assigning value to the `@currentMember` as `teal-dark` or as `'teal-dark'`. If your variable value has quotes for some reason then you can use the method mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614621/less-mixin-output-values-without-quotes/19614647#19614647) answer to remove it from the output.

Comment: i have to use string otherwise it will interpolate colors like `grey` to `#808080` which I don't want.

Comment: Got you mate. In that case the solution mentioned in the answer that I linked in my previous comment is your best bet. Also Less v2.0 and higher would not do the color name to hex code auto conversion. So upgrading the Less compiler would also help :)

Comment: @harry upgrading does not help. Indeed colored names are not be converted to their hex value anymore, but `grey` is still a color not a string.

Comment: @BassJobsen: True mate. I stand corrected. I just confused it a bit with using variables as property values. It wouldn't work for selector interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names and

```
@current-member: teal-dark;
@teal-dark: red;

.@{current-member} {
color: @@current-member;
}
```

compiles into:

```
.teal-dark {
  color: red;
}
```

Possible relevant questions:

- [Defining Variable Variables using LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198221/defining-variable-variables-using-less-css)
- [Dynamic class names in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899497/dynamic-class-names-in-less)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix from another post:

```
    @selector: ~'.@{currentMember}';
    @{selector} div { background: ~"@{@{currentMember}}" };
```